# Authentication not working inside corporate network

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms, adal

For a company, we are using `Xamarin` in combination with `ADAL.NET` to access a web-api which is connected to an `Azure Active Directory`. When the user logs in, it works fine. However when we are inside the network of the company, we get a `404` response when we get redirected to the corresponding `ADFS` server.

After some research we came to know that the company uses two different servers to login. One to handle internal requests, and one for traffic outside the network.

So, we are using an emulator to test the app. We changed the `hosts` file to redirect to the external server which made the login working.  (We redirected `adfs.******.nl` to the `IP` of the external server.)

Now the question is, how do I fix this inside our app? The company does not want to change their redirects, since it will break more applications like Sharepoint and others.

I read something about this:
https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/ADAL-.NET-Q-&-A#why-does-adal-for-windows-store-fails-when-in-corporate-network-while-it-succeeds-otherwise

But that's only for `Windows`.

Here is how we do the current request:

```
public static async Task<string> Login()
{
    AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(_authority);
    authContext.TokenCache.Clear();
    return (await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(_resourceId, _clientId, _redirect, PlatformParameters)).AccessToken;
}
```

Comment: Does it not need ports open to get to talk to the azure AD

Comment: I know you said no changes to current infra. However, my guess is if you could get a DNS record that would resolve the external ADFS when queried externally and internal ADFS when queried internally, would solve your problems. That is, assuming ADFS servers are set up so that this would be possible. Other option is to use something else for authentication, like ws-fed and explicitly tell it to use the external ADFS server. Problem with Azure AD is that it is only aware of the external ADFS, if it's unavailable, then authentication fails. Ws-Fed would bypass Azure AD, which I bet you don't want

Comment: @kim that't exactly what happens now. That DNS record already exists.

Comment: @GiovanniTerlingen what I had in mind is kinda what is explained here https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/networking/2015/05/12/split-brain-dns-deployment-using-windows-dns-server-policies/ it's called a "split-brain" DNS deployment. That way internal users get the IP of the internal server and external ones get the external IP of the other ADFS. Is this how it's configured at the moment?

Comment: Yes it is exactly what happens now, which causes the problem.

Comment: Usually when you are in the external network, you are redirected to the ADFS WAP (Web Application Proxy) which has FBA (Forms Based Authentication) enabled. And when you are in the internal network, you are redirected to the ADFS server itself (which usually only has Windows Integrated Authentication enabled). So I would check how is the internal authentication configured in ADFS; if FBA is disabled, I would try to enable it, to see if that fixes the problem. More info https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/operations/configure-authentication-policies